# Accessing Object and Property via Variable?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have a namespace setup like

```
mySpace.util = {

    valid: {

          first: function() {
               //blah
          }

    }

}
```

I am trying to pass the `valid` and `first` as variables to access the function ? I've tried:

`mySpace.util.[variable1[variable2]()]` but that doesn't work ? I am trying to pass variables so I get `mySpace.util.valid.first()`

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = 'valid',
    meth = 'first';

mySpace.util[obj][meth]();
```

Comment: awesome :) thanks heaps. 1 bracket! why I oughttaaa .... haha