# Reference a value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I have a couple of check boxes that I'd like to use their "name" attribute as the value I reference within my array.

Let's say I have an array like so:

```
var test = {
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
}

var someBtn = "one";
```

How can I say the following?

```
test.someBtn; // Which would translate to test.one
```

Obviously, test.someBtn does not work. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm confused. The `test` in your question is an object, not an array.

Comment: A better title would be "Access a JavaScript property by a variable" - search for this and there will be *many* duplicates.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424885/accessing-object-and-property-via-variable , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refer to it as if it were an array:

```
test[someBtn]
```